# 100% Native C Application on Android?

Tags: android, android-ndk

Is there anyway I could write 100% native C code for Android?  I know there are ways to write some C code inside Java code, but I don't know any Java and I hate Java anyway.

Is there anyway I could write pure C code that will run under Android?

Comment: You don't know any Java and yet you hate Java? You're making my brain hurt.

Comment: "i dont know any java and i hate java anyway" ... Don't let language favoritism hold you back as a developer. Learn the tools of your trade.

Comment: There is no way to have an application that is 0% java and which runs in Android.  Android apps run in a java VM.

Comment: If you hate Java anyway, it follows that you should hate Android anyway, no?

Comment: seriously, you hate java? that's like a carpenter saying, i really love my lathe, but f those f-ing squares over there. And Hammers... don't even get me started on hammers... Java, C++ are almost the same language syntactically

Comment: You're all ignoring one thing, you don't know if the OP is speaking in C or in C++, in the first case he might be saying that he doesn't like to program using OO.

In the second case, I also don't like very much the approach of the android SDK, of having to write tons of xml files, it promotes the mentality that programming is much more muscle than brains, and hence it falls in what Joel calls Java Schools (or lazy programmers). 

Not to mention that one can just program using almost only refactorings without design at all.

Comment: @Coyote21  Huh?  `tons of XML files` - you mean data, describing the view hierarchy,which can also be done in code if you prefer? There is only one XML file which you MUST create, which is the manifest. Or are you talking about something else?  Layout XML has nothing to do with muscle vs brain but rather the entirely proper concept of separating presentation data from logic.

Comment: I hate Java too, while loving C with all my soul. +1 for this question, I was looking for the same

Comment: Just to clarify to others, why I hate java: it is damn slow and you cant write inline assembly with it

Comment: Java on Android runs 4 times slower than C. Java sucks. Source: http://www.androidauthority.com/java-vs-c-app-performance-689081/

Answer (score 11):

There is, as of Android 2.3: [`NativeActivity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NativeActivity.html). But you don't get access to any of the niceties of Android's Java libraries; you're on your own in the wild west. This is really intended for people writing high-performance games.

Comment: With NativeActivity, *your* code might be "pure" C, but it still runs in a process that includes the Dalvik virtual machine, and your "pure" C code has been started by a JNI call from Java... Just get over your "hate" or Java, or stop developing for Android...

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is support for writing completely native activities. You can check out the [native-activity](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/overview.html) sample application.

I would not recommend this path, though, as in my experience applications that are heavy in NDK code are very difficult to debug. I would rate the Android native debugging experience as lacking.

**Edit** - one caveat is that you will still be doing plently of Java--just through the JNI.

Comment: Very true. I'm converting an application into C and it has been quite fun lol. Not for the faint-hearted that's for sure.

Answer (score 2):

Might be more trouble than it's worth, you could possibly write your logic in C code and import that to java using extern or external (I forget which now) and then do the GUI in java. There's really no point to using straight C in android unless you want to REALLY optimized your logic. Most of the calls you can make are wrapped anyways so you would have to make those calls to access certain things on an android device. Long story short : not a good idea unless you need faster logic.

Comment: I can think of lots of reasons to use a language other than Java. a) existing code bases b) team knowledge base c) code re-use on multiple platforms (ios etc). These kinds of answers are what send the ameuters  on wild goose chases...

Answer (score 2):

You can write most of the application in C around a NativeActivity.  However, some Android features can only be used from Java, so you'll need to use JNI instead of pure native.  See the official [overview](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/overview.html).

Comment: When using NativeActivity, does it mean that the c application can't call java methods ?

Comment: @ransh Yes, you can call Java methods from C: that is precisely what JNI (Java Native Interface) is for